# How do i append data in a QTableView by clicking a button?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

I am using a `QTableView` to show content from my database. The program has 2 `QLineEdits`: `self.nameSlot` and `self.amountSlot`. I also has `self.toDay` which is a `QdateEdit`. When i insert new data to the database using `self.applyButton`, it works as required but the data is not appended to the `QTableView`. How do i solve that problem? This is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtSql
from Printer import PrintView
from database import DatabaseInfo
import Sky2


class Sky(QtGui.QMainWindow, Sky2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.database = DatabaseInfo()
        self.database.setup()

        self.applyButton.clicked.connect(self.new_client)

        self.toDay.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.toDay.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())

        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableView.setShowGrid(False)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        # failed to use sort
        # self.tableView.sortByColumn(self, 2, QtCore.Qt.SortOrder(0))
        database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        database.setDatabaseName('database.db')
        database.open()
        self.table_model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        self.table_model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Clients ")
        self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Amount")
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Date")

    def new_client(self):
        name = self.nameSlot.text()
        amount = self.amountSlot.text()
        date = self.toDay.text()
        self.database.add_client(name, amount, date)
        self.table_model.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
        # print('success')

   def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_P:
            self.printing()

    def printing(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.ScreenResolution)
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)
        view = PrintView()
        view.setModel(self.tableView.model())
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(view.print_)
        dialog.exec_()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Sky()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSqlQueryModel` is not notified of changes so if you want to get new information you must request it through `setQuery()`

```
def new_client(self):
    name = self.nameSlot.text()
    amount = self.amountSlot.text()
    date = self.toDay.text()
    self.database.add_client(name, amount, date)
    self.table_model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Clients ")
```

If you are going to work with a table, you could use `QSqlTableModel` in a simple and elective way, and you could add elements through `QSqlRecord()` and the `insertRecord()` method, with this method the model is notified because the order is done by the model.

```
class Sky(QtGui.QMainWindow, Sky2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.applyButton.clicked.connect(self.new_client)

        self.toDay.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.toDay.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())

        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableView.setShowGrid(False)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        # failed to use sort
        # self.tableView.sortByColumn(self, 2, QtCore.Qt.SortOrder(0))
        self.database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.database.setDatabaseName('database.db')
        if not self.database.open():
            self.close()
        self.table_model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.table_model.setTable("Clients")
        self.table_model.select()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Amount")
        self.table_model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Date")

    def new_client(self):
        name = self.nameSlot.text()
        amount = self.amountSlot.text()
        date = self.toDay.text()
        record = self.table_model.record()
        record.setValue("Name", name)
        record.setValue("Amount", amount)
        record.setValue("Date", date)
        self.table_model.insertRecord(self.table_model.rowCount(), record)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. i knew i was missing something small